# Cast a class that is dynamically obtained

Tags: java, generics, casting, classloader

I am trying to cast a class that I dynamically obtain that has implemented an interface. I have tried the following below but it doesn't seem to work. How I achieve this.

```
public InterfaceX test(){

 InterfaceX x = null;
 Class<?> classX = Class.forName("com.TestClassX");
 x = (InterfaceX) classX;
 return  x;

}
```

EDIT:
I dont want to create an instance, since I am just looking to simply call a static method defined by the interface.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  You're only ever going to get back `null`.

Comment: Are you trying to create and cast an object of that class? In itself, the class is not an instance of anything other than a class.

Comment: You're casting a value of type `Class` to `InterfaceX`. This will never work. `Class` is `final` and does not implement `InterfaceX`.

Comment: If the static method is defined in a known interface, just invoke it. There's no reason to do what you are attempting.

Comment: I want to call a static method of the class, by simply doing x.someStaticMethod()

Comment: `x` is an `InterfaceX`. Does `InterfaceX` define `someStaticMethod()`? Then just do `InterfaceX.someStaticMethod()`. Polymorphism does not apply to `static` method.

Comment: I'm still not sure how dynamic access is related to your code, but you might want to look into using reflection to invoke methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Comment: Inheritance and static methods don't really get along.  Additionally, interfaces couldn't even define static methods until Java 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `x` is a `Class` object, you cannot do `x.staticMethod()`. However, this is possible using reflection.

```
public interface Interface {
    static void method() {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Then, in the main class you can do this.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class Main  {

    public static void invokeMethod(String className)  {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
            Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method");
            method.invoke(null);   // null is used for static methods. For instance methods, pass the instance.
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        invokeMethod("Interface");
    }
}
```

This works, but you should generally try to avoid using reflection (anything in `java.lang.reflect`). Most of the time there is a better solution to the problem you are trying to solve.